# Difficulty in understanding a statement in the proof of the correctness of $\text{BFS}$ algorithm as dealt with in CLRS

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I was going through section of *Breadth First Search* of the text *Introduction to Algorithms* by *Cormen et. al.* and I faced difficulty in understanding a statement in the proof below which I have marked with $\dagger$

> Theorem: (**Correctness of breadth-first search**)
>
> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed or undirected graph, and suppose that $BFS$ is run on $G$ from a given source vertex $s \in V$. Then, during its execution, $BFS$ discovers every vertex $v \in V$ that is reachable from the source $s$, and upon termination, $d[v] = \delta(s, v)$ for all $v \in V$. Moreover, for any vertex $v \neq s$ that is reachable from $s$, one of the shortest paths from $s$ to $v$ is a shortest path from $s$ to $\pi[v]$ followed by the edge $(\pi[v], v)$.
>
> $\left[ \delta(s,v) \rightarrow \text{Length of the shortest path from s to v}\\ d[v]\rightarrow \text{distance assigned to vertex $v$ from $s$ by BFS}\\\pi[v]\rightarrow \text{Predecessor of $v$ in the path from $s$ to $v$ in the BFS}\right]$
>
> > **Proof**:
> >
> > Assume, for the purpose of contradiction, that some vertex receives a $d$ value not equal to its shortest path distance. Let $v$ be the vertex with minimum $\delta(s, v)$ that receives such an incorrect $d$ value; clearly $v \neq s$. We know $d[v] \geq \delta(s, v)$, and thus we have that $d[v] > \delta(s, v)$. Vertex $v$ must be reachable from $s$, for if it is not, then $\delta(s, v) = \infty \geq d[v]$. Let $u$ be the vertex immediately preceding $v$ on a shortest path from $s$ to $v$, so that $\delta(s, v) = \delta(s, u) + 1$. Because $\delta(s, u) < \delta(s, v)$, and ***because of how we chose $v$ , we have $d[u] = \delta(s, u)$$^\dagger$***. Putting these properties together, we have
> >
> > $d[v] > \delta(s, v) = \delta(s, u) + 1 = d[u] + 1 $
> >
> > (The proof then continues, but I do not include the rest here...)

I could not understand the reasoning behind the statement marked with $\dagger$, $\text{"because of how we chose $v$ , we have $d[u] = \delta(s, u)$"}$

Comment: "Let  be the vertex with **minimum** $\delta(s,v)$, that receives such an incorrect value $d$". I.e., for all $u$ such that $\delta(s,u) < \delta(s,v)$, we have $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$.

Comment: @Dmitry I do not get the intuition, for me it seems the same thing as written in the text. Might be it is quite simple but I am unable to share the same view as you do. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh The vertex $u$ has a smaller $\delta$ than $v$, since $\delta(s,v)=\delta(s,u)+1>\delta(s,u)$. The vertex $v$ was chosen to be a vertex that, among the vertices with wrong $d$, has smallest $\delta$. Since $u$ has a smaller $\delta$ than $v$, then $u$ cannot have a wrong $d$.

Comment: @plop aah now I get it.. Thanks for the help. $\text{The way the vertex $v$  is chosen}$ , from this line I was trying to correlate the choosing of $v$ by the $BFS$ algorithm. But they are actually pointing to the assumption they made in choosing $v$ for the proof. My though was wrong (now that I see) because $BFS$ does not **choose** a vertex. Once again thanks for the help...

Comment: The proof can also be reformulated as induction on $\delta(s,v)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perhaps more illuminating to reformulate this proof by contradiction as a proof by induction. We prove that $d[v] = \delta(s,v)$ by induction on the latter (the case $\delta(s,v) = \infty$ should be taken care of separately). If $\delta(s,v) = 0$ then $v = s$, and indeed $d[s] = 0$. Now suppose that the result holds for all vertices at distance $i$ from $s$, and consider a vertex $v$ at distance $i+1$ from $s$. Let $u$ be a neighbor of $v$ at distance $i$ from $s$. By induction, $d[u] = \delta(s,u)$, and so once $u$ is processed, $d[v] \leq \delta(s,u) + 1 = \delta(s,v)$. Since $d[v] \geq \delta(s,v)$, it follows that $d[v] = \delta(s,v)$, as needed.

How do the two proofs relate? Let $U$ be the set of vertices such that $d[v] = \delta(s,v)$; clearly $s \in U$. Let $v \neq s$ be an arbitrary vertex reachable from $s$, and let $u$ be a predecessor of $v$, that is, a neighbor of $v$ such that $\delta(s,v) = \delta(s,u) + 1$. The proof shows that if $u \in U$ then also $v \in U$. You can now proceed in two different ways:

- Proof by contradiction: choose $v \in U$ minimizing $\delta(s,v)$. By definition, the predecessor of $v$ does lie in $U$, and so we reach a contradiction.
- Proof by induction: we show that all vertices reachable from $s$ are in $U$, by induction on their distance from $s$.

The two proofs are equivalent. I prefer the second.

Comment: Thanks for the help.